# Are there statically-typed programming-languages with inheritance where method parameters are contravariant?

Tags: inheritance, language-agnostic, types, contravariance

Theoretically it is sound to override methods of a parent in a subclass with a method where the parameters are supertypes of the parameters in the parent class, like:

```
class T
  def foo(s: String) = ...

class S
  override def foo(a: Any) = ...
```

Which programming languages support this "feature" and how do they solve issues like the possibility that a single method of a subclass can override multiple methods of a parent class:

```
class T
  def foo(s: String) = ...
  def foo(i: Int)    = ...

class S
  override def foo(a: Any) = ...
```

(Assuming that `String` and `Int` subtypes of `Any`.)

Comment: If you are talking about statically typed languages than I don't know. Dynamically typed languages care not about this issue so I assume you are talking about statically typed languages. Please note it in your question.

Comment: WIkipedia asserts that a language called "Sather" has contravariance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Sather, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sather), but I can't vouch for its accuracy.

Comment: i don't know such language but i see no problem with the fact that a method can override multiple methods from super-class. when you do `sInstance.foo(anyObject)` then this method is called. not `T.foo(String)` nor `T.foo(Int)`. There is no problem for compiler. just you, as a programmer, have to design your classes so this invocation makes sense

Answer (score 2):

(Incomplete answer) If we take the example of OCaml, it answers the title of your question: this a "statically-typed programming language with inheritance where method parameters are contravariant".

As for the second part of your question ("how do they solve issues like..."), the Gordian knot is cut by not allowing overloading. (Overloading means having two functions with the same name but different argument types, which makes type inference a lot harder).

Answer (score 0):

Although I grasp the concepts, I don't know if I fully understand your question.  Namely, it sounds like you're saying that the derived classes should be able to implement overrides of methods that use parameters which are 'less' derived.  That seems backwards to me.  It seems like the overriding method should only be able to use 'more' derived types.  Maybe that's what you meant, or maybe I'm mistaken about that, but here's a quote of what C# 4.0 allows for:

(Taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

What is variance for generic type parameters?
This is a new feature in C# 4.0. Now, when creating a generic interface, you can specify whether there is an implicit conversion between interface instances that have different type arguments. For example, you can use an interface instance that has methods with more derived return types than originally specified (covariance) or that has methods with less derived parameter types (contravariance). The same rules are applied to generic delegates.

Comment: "That seems backwards to me" - it isn't, it's correct. If the function `foo` in the base class can accept any String, then the override `foo` *must* as a bare minimum accept any String, otherwise it breaks LSP. What contravariance does is allow it, in addition, to accept other things. Taking a super-type of String does that, it allows String and other things. It's the flip-side of return type covariance, which says that if a base class promises to return a String, then a derived class can be more specific about what it returns, and only produce certain sub-types of String.

Comment: Ah, I see I wasn't qute reading my own quotation correctly.  I see that's exactly what it says now.